# Translating GeoTIFF in XYZ using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, xyz

I try translate GeoTIFF file which 2GB in XYZ with this code

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from osgeo import gdal

path = 'D:\Temp\Work\Data\big_dem.tif'

ds = gdal.Open(path)

xyz = gdal.Translate('big_dem.xyz', ds)
```

When i run last string of code, i get error:

> "Received a NULL pointer"

because `type(ds) = NoneType`.

I think GDAL can't open big GeoTIFF file. How solve this problem?

Comment: try: `path = r'D:\Temp\Work\Data\big_dem.tif'`

Comment: If you think that the reason is due to big size of the tiff you should test the hypothesis by trying to open a small tiff from the same location.

Comment: @BERA is telling you to try a raw string so that python does not interpret the "\" backslash as an Escape Sequence.  That is what the "r" in front is.  https://www.journaldev.com/23598/python-raw-string

Comment: Yes, when the path is incorrect the `type(ds)` will be None. and maybe you should include a full path for the output. With those changes your code is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an r in front of your path (raw string) and specify a full output path:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os

path = r'D:\Temp\Work\Data\big_dem.tif'

if os.path.exists(path): #If the path is valid translate
    ds = gdal.Open(path)
    xyz = gdal.Translate(r'D:\Temp\Work\Data\big_dem_translated.xyz', ds)
    print('Finished')
else:
    print('The path is invalid')
```

Comment: @Ivan_Chay because `'\b'` is interpreted by Python as the `ASCII Backspace` [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html#:~:text=The%20recognized%20escape%20sequences%20are) so your path becomes `'D:\Temp\Work\Datig_dem.tif'` unless you use a raw string (`r'D:\Temp\etc...'`), escape all the backslashes (`'D:\\Temp\\etc...'`) or use forward slashes (`'D:/Temp/etc...'`)